# Something with .txt File?

Tags: gedit, text, file-format, text-processing, hidden-files

I have stored a text  as .txt while saving it in Gedit in Ubuntu 14.04.

But after viewing that folder, which i have stored will have two files with that name but with 'Tilde Symbol' **'~'** for an another file and it will be hidden!!!

Say **'a.txt'** means the folder will contain **'~a.txt'** too, which can be viewed only by making them unhidden

Why is it so? What does it mean? Any Problem/Error with that?

How to Rectify it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are just backups of your original files that **gedit** creates before saving changes to your edited documents.

**How to prevent this ?**

In **gedit** preferences you need to disable Create a backup copy of file before saving, and if you want to automatic save your edits automatically set a timer with the option enable **Autosave** files every **X minutes**.

That way the **~** will be gone and your last changes will be saved on the file every x minutes in case something goes bad or your computer crashes.

The changes made to the file will be saved to the file itself and not to a temporary file.

Please be aware that if you delete the contents of a file and auto save is enable there will be a chance that you end up with a saved empty file.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Prashant Chikhalkar. But using Gedit will be fine or any suggestion for an alternate of Gedit?

Comment: Does this answer helped you ? I'll check for other options too .. I'll update you once get something useful

Answer (score 0):

The problem is pretty simple, actually. You can get to know it by viewing the properties of that file. It's a backup file for the text, `a.txt` for example. the `~a.txt` stores the last save (probably) of the file (`a.txt`). You can delete the backup file (`~a.txt`) if you want to. For some small files this is unnecessary.